# Varnish 4.1 segfault in Docker

Tags: linux, varnish, docker, segmentation-fault, glibc

I'm trying to use Varnish 4.1 with Docker (1.9.1).
I've built a docker image in Alpine Linux 3.2 with its musl-libc to reduce the image size.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.2
​
RUN echo 'http://dl-4.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.3/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk update && apk upgrade -U -a && \
    apk add --update varnish \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*
Add Comment
```

When I try to run inside of the container, sometimes I get a segfault, but sometimes I don't:

```bash
# varnishd -F -W epoll -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl
child (4081) Started
Pushing vcls failed:
CLI communication error (hdr)
Stopping Child
Child (4081) died signal=11
Child (4081) Panic message:
Assert error in child_sigsegv_handler(), mgt/mgt_child.c line 297:
  Condition(Segmentation fault by instruction at 0x7f8bec8af9e8) not true.
version = varnish-4.1.0 revision 3041728
ident = Linux,3.13.0-66-generic,x86_64,-junix,-smalloc,-smalloc,-hcritbit,epoll
​
Could not create _.vsm.4071: File exists
```

Sometimes when I get 2-3 segfaults in a row and 3rd, 4th time it runs successfully.

My environment:

```bash
# gcc --version
gcc (Alpine 5.2.0) 5.2.0
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
​
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Alpine Linux"
ID=alpine
VERSION_ID=3.2.3
PRETTY_NAME="Alpine Linux v3.2"
HOME_URL="http://alpinelinux.org"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.alpinelinux.org"
​
# ldd --version
musl libc
Version 1.1.12

# docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
​
Server:
 Version:      1.9.1
 API version:  1.21
 Go version:   go1.4.2
 Git commit:   a34a1d5
 Built:        Fri Nov 20 13:12:04 UTC 2015
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Also, when I run it successfully and try to clear cache (ban), child process exits with a segfault.

Is it caused by musl-libc?

Comment: What is `ADD Comment` in your Dockerfile? I suspect that it is not meant to be there.

Comment: It's just a miscopying, I don't actually have this line in my Dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the exact same issue. Seems to come from the alpine image. Switched to ubuntu and it works fine.